# Highlight grid cells which line passes through in line chart matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a line chart consisting of a curve with a colored grid as follows:

[image]

How can I have every grid cell which the curve passes through to be highlighted like this, without changing the original curve function for more datapoints:

[image]

I use matplotlib **hist2d** with colorbar, however, the function only returns a grid in which only the cells containing datapoints are highlighted.

Below is the code I use for the first chart:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

def arange(start, stop, step, include_stop=True):
    return np.arange(start, stop + 1e-9, step)
def min_max_scale_array(arr):
    arr = np.array(arr)
    return (arr - arr.min())/(arr.max()-arr.min())

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 10)
y = x**2
x = min_max_scale_array(x)
y = min_max_scale_array(y)

""" Plot """
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, color="red")
ax.scatter(x, y, marker="o", color="red")
""" Show Grid And Color Bar """
ax.set_xticks(arange(0, 1, 1/12))
ax.set_yticks(arange(0, 1, 1/12))
grid, _, _, image = plt.hist2d(x, y, bins=(12, 12))
plt.grid(True)       
plt.colorbar()    
ax.margins(0)
plt.show()
""" Grid Array """        
print(np.flipud(grid.T))
```

Comment: Somehow you need to check whether the line segments pass through the values contained in a grid. hist2d does this only for points. If you wrote it more manually you would also need to check whether function values fall within a box, which would also involve adding points. The only other way I can think of is to do it spatially with polygons and lines - use geopandas to see if the lines intersect the polygons. But I would be very surprised if this was less computationally intensive than just adding points. Can you add points and then remove them again for plotting?

Comment: @pasnik thank you for your suggestion I just ask to see if there is any way to do this with existing code or libraries since adding more points does not feel right